# Why use "/bin/bash -c $command" instead of calling "$command" directly?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Often times, I encounter commands being executed with `/bin/bash -c` or `/bin/sh -c` instead of directly. For example, instead of `cp /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2`, it'd be `/bin/bash -c "cp /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2"`.

What are some reasons for doing this instead of executing the command directly? In recent memory, I've seen this the most in Docker and K8s commands. The only thing I can really think of is because you specifically want to run the command with a specific shell, but this seems like a pretty rare/niche use-case?

[Here](https://github.com/getredash/contrib-helm-chart/blob/master/templates/server-deployment.yaml#L40-L41) is a specific example, the k8s deployment uses:

```
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", ". /config/dynamicenv.sh && /app/bin/docker-entrypoint server"]
```

Instead of what I would expect the default to be:

```
. /config/dynamicenv.sh && /app/bin/docker-entrypoint server
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without specific examples it's hard to tell, but a common reason for doing this is that you want to make use of shell i/o redirection, pipes, etc. For example, this fragment of a Kubernetes pod manifest would fail because it involves a pipe, which requires the shell to execute the command line:

```
containers:
  image: docker.io/alpine:latest
  command:
    - echo hello world | sed s/world/container/
```

But this would work:

```
containers:
  image: docker.io/alpine:latest
  command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - echo hello world | sed s/world/container/
```

This is one relatively common situation in which you'll see things explicitly execute with a shell. If you'd like to update your question with some specific examples, we can provide a more thorough answer.

---

Your example is very close to what I've already included here in my answer. The command `. /config/dynamicenv.sh && /app/bin/docker-entrypoint server` isn't a simple command; it's a shell script that makes use of both the `.` and the `&&` operators.

If they were to write:

```
command: [". /config/dynamicenv.sh && /app/bin/docker-entrypoint server"]
```

It would fail with an error along the lines of:

```
exec: "[\". /config/dynamicenv.sh && /app/bin/docker-entrypoint server\"]": stat [". /config/dynamicenv.sh && /app/bin/docker-entrypoint server"]: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

The command needs to be wrapped with `sh -c` in order to execute correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited the question with a specific example.

Comment: I've updated the answer in response to your example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Much appreciated. If you don't mind, could you please expand on the following (paraphrased) statement: "commands with pipes, complex operators, etc fail because it requires a shell  to execute". What is the container using instead of a shell? And why does the container use the default "non-shell" thing?

Comment: The argument to `command` is expected to be a binary, and the container executes it directly (e.g., using one of the `exec()` family of system calls). If you want to run something that isn't a binary, but instead requires some sort of interpreter, you need to be explicit about that.

Comment: Ah, that makes so much sense now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Re "*The argument to command is expected to be a binary*", It's expected to be an executable. Not necessarily a binary.